# Reverse engineering spherical model equations

Tags: generalized-linear-model, least-squares

I have been needing to fit an $n$-sphere to some data points, and found a useful set of equations [here](https://www.jpe-innovations.com/downloads/Fit-sphere-through-points.pdf).  However, there is no derivation for the formulae in that source, and I need to implement a weighting scheme, for which the derivation would be useful.

To paraphrase the equations in the link a bit, if $X$ is our matrix of row-vector data, and $\bar{x}$ is the mean vector over the features, and we let:

$ A = 2 X^T (X - \bar{x}) / n \ \ \ \ $ (broadcast $X - \bar{x}$ appropriately)
$ B = X X^T (X-\bar{x})/n $

Then the best fit is achieved at:

$x_{\text{center}} = (A^T A)^{-1} A^TB^T$

and

$r = ||X - x_{\text{center}}||_F / \sqrt{n}$

In some basic experiments, this all seems to check out.  Based on statements in the linked paper, and the equation for $r$, it seems that the objective is:

$L = \sum (||x - x_{\text{center}}||^2 - r^2)^2$

Most interestingly, the formula for $x_{\text{center}}$ looks just like the solution to [OLS linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation), which causes me to suspect some sort of change of variables.  However, if that is the case it strikes me as strange that $A$ is a square matrix.

In any case, I am having a difficult time figuring out how these formulae were derived.  Can anyone give me some hints as to how to interpret this as a change of variables into a linear model, or however else one might derive these equations?

Comment: Do you know the radius of the sphere you're trying to fit? If so, you might check out the Hough Transform, as it works particularly well with missing data.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, I do not.  My ultimate goal is to fit a lot of these things, so fast, closed-form equations would be amazing.  Also, it seems that the Hough transform finds the most-circular thing in an image potentially containing other stuff.  I want to fit one sphere to all of my data.

Comment: Ah, I see. Incidentally, you can typeset norms by using `\|x\|` - they look much better. Also, I would recommend a displayed fraction `\dfrac{num}{denom}` for your $r$ equation.

Comment: A suitable way to fit spheres will depend on your assumptions about how the points might not all fall on a common sphere--that is, your assumptions about the errors.  If there are no errors, this is a purely mathematical problem with a relatively simple solution; but otherwise, could you please tell us about the data you have and its inherent error?

Comment: @whuber, I am most interested in orthogonal errors to the sphere surface.  I.e. the least squares loss would be $L = \sum(\|x - x_{\text{center}}\| - r)^2$.  However, it seems that manipulating this equation presents some difficulties, and so perhaps the authors have employed a different loss function to help with that.  This may be fine, since I need a speedy algorithm to solve the problem.  Since the authors of the formulae in the question have found a closed-form solution (!!), I am currently interested in exploring their solution further.